# Dynamic query inside if exists is not working

Tags: sql, sql-server, variables

I am writing Dynamic SQL inside If exists. I have a query on `sys.columns` to check that department Id column exists or not. If it exists I have to check row count and go inside if statement. I am not able to get mistake in my query. Someone please point out.

```
DECLARE @TableName VARCHAR(100) = '[Student]'
DECLARE @ColName VARCHAR(10) = 'DeptId'
DECLARE @Query NVARCHAR(1000) = '
    SELECT *
    FROM sys.columns
    WHERE Name =' + @ColName + 'AND Object_ID = Object_ID(' + @TableName + ')'

DECLARE @rowcnt INT

EXEC sp_executesql @query

SELECT @rowcnt = @@ROWCOUNT

IF (@rowcnt > 0)
    BEGIN
        PRINT 'row present'
    END
```

> ERROR - Incorrect syntax near 'Object_ID'.

And it always returns row count as 1.

Comment: Are you using MS SQL Server or Oracle (plsql)? Don't tag products not involved...

Comment: I am using MS SQL Server

Comment: why do you you need dynamic sql?

Comment: Because I have to do this for many tables. This will happen inside a loop for each table

Comment: still no need for dynamic sql. try without!

Comment: Put your `@ColName` and `@TableName` in single quote

Comment: @KrishnrajRana What is proper escape sequence to add single quote. Apology for basic question but I am struggling to find one

Comment: @TBAG: you can use `QUOTENAME` function for that. So your query now look like this - `DECLARE @Query  NVARCHAR(1000) = 'SELECT * FROM sys.columns WHERE Name =' + QUOTENAME(@ColName, '''') + ' AND Object_ID = Object_ID(' + QUOTENAME(@TableName, '''') + ')'`

Comment: @TBAG, to escape a single quote (`'`), use two single quotes (`''`).  Because you're placing the single quote right before the end of your string, it would like like this:  `Name =''' + @ColName + '''`.  That is triple-quoting: two to indicate that the string contains an apostrophe, one to indicate the end of the string.

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to tell what's wrong, but I'll let you fix the query because there are a lot of options.  The query returns an error.  I'm not sure why `@@ROWCOUNT` is returned as 1, but you are missing single quotes for the `Name`.  So, in all likelihood, you are going to get an error that `DEPTID` is not a valid column.

You can naively fix this by putting in the single quotes.  But, you should be using that arguments to `sp_execute_sql` to pass arguments in.

And, I'll add that this is probably unnecessary, because normally one would do:

```
if (exists (select 1
            from information_schema.columns
            where table_name = @table_name and column_name = @column_name
           )
   )
begin
 . . .
end;
```

Of course, this doesn't do the object resolution from the name, but that is rarely needed, especially if you are not putting strange characters in table and column names.

Comment: What will be escape sequence to add single quote. Sorry for basic query. I am struggling to find this.

Comment: `@TBAG . . . The relevant extract looks like `'WHERE Name = ''' + @ColName + ''' AND`.  Two single quotes in a row are interpreted as a single quote within a string.

Answer (score 0):

Fortunately dynamic SQL isn't needed in this case. You can use a parameterized query.

```
SELECT @rowcnt = COUNT(*)
FROM sys.columns
WHERE [name] = @ColName
AND [object_id] = OBJECT_ID(@TableName)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @TableName SYSNAME = 'dbo.test',
        @ColName SYSNAME = 'col1'

IF COL_LENGTH(@TableName, @ColName) IS NOT NULL
    PRINT 'column present'
```

Comment: You might know why this works, but some word of explanation might be helpful for others.

Comment: If column does not exist `COL_LENGTH` returns null. This is a standard behavior.